# Class "PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Responsive" not found Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, responsive, livewire-powergrid

Good morning, I am trying to use the responsive class in powergrid but I get the error:

Class "PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Responsive" not found.

I have installed the latest version of PowerGrid for laravel and configured everything but I get this error, I am calling the responsive class in the function setUp()

```
public function setUp(): array
    {
        $this->showCheckBox();

        return [
            Exportable::make('export'))
                ->striped()
                ->type(Exportable::TYPE_XLS, Exportable::TYPE_CSV),
            Header::make()->showSearchInput(),
            Footer::make()
                ->showPerPage()
                ->showRecordCount(),
            Responsive::make()
        ];
    }
```

As indicated in the documentation

Comment: what is the version you're using? Check https://github.com/Power-Components/livewire-powergrid

Comment: Im using 4.X version of powergrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class "PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Responsive"` is only available if you are using tailwind theme of Powergrid. These class is **not available for the bootstrap theme**.

I hope this will help you!